# On what basis requireCsrfProtectionMatcher is initialised in csrfFilter

Tags: spring-security, csrf

The CsrfFilter has a validation

```
if (!this.requireCsrfProtectionMatcher.matches(request)) {
            filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
            return;
        }
```

in the above snippet, this.requireCsrfProtectionMatcher is getting initialised to AndRequestMatcher. But I want to use only DefaultRequiresCsrfMatcher. Can anyone please provide more information about this?
My security Configuration

```
 @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
          http.csrf().and().
          cors().and()
            .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
            .and()
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/rest/open/**").permitAll()
            .and().authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/**").authenticated()
            .anyRequest().permitAll()
            .and()
            .oauth2ResourceServer()
            .jwt()
            .jwtAuthenticationConverter(getJwtAuthoritiesConverter());
            

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `requireCsrfProtectionMatcher` is being initialized with `AndRequestMatcher` because you are using `oauth2ResourceServer().jwt()`.

The `oauth2ResourceServer` DSL tells the `CsrfFilter` to ignore requests which contain a `Bearer` token. You can check it in the [source code](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/blob/879b2d089faa8a379b1a427e91a847cc4bf78f57/config/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/config/annotation/web/configurers/oauth2/server/resource/OAuth2ResourceServerConfigurer.java#L319).

Since the JWT authentication is stateless, you would not need a CSRF token in the request.

Comment: Does it mean in scenarios where bearer token is passed CSRF token validation is not required ?

Comment: In theory not, because JWT is stateless authentication and usually doesn't use cookies to carry the authentication token.